# react-native app doenst respond to orientation change

Tags: react-native, device-orientation

i have a strange problem with my react-native app. On Emulator and real device, the app doesnt response to orientation change.

I use react-navigation with StackNavigator and native-base for UI.

> AndroidManifest contains
>   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

```
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.13",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
"native-base": "^2.13.8"
```

But the problem was present also with previous modules and react-native version.

Thanks

**Fixed**

Adding android:screenOrientation="sensor" resolve the problem.

Comment: How have you enabled orientation change ?

Comment: Please provide more information including your code

Comment: If you set up everything right and you dont know why it doesnt work I had a similar problem. In my case the only thing that I forgot was to turn on the Orientation Change on the emulator. So pull down the status-bar and see if the screen isnt locked on top.

Comment: @gprathour yes, auto rotation enabled in emulator. But this happen also on real device with rotation enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the orientation:
For iOS like the picture below:
[image]

For Android in Manifest
[Android Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53221517/android-portrait-and-landscape)

Comment: The key is android:screenOrientation="sensor" in AndroidManifest.xml .Thanks!